# Style picture element

Tags: html, css

I'm learning adaptive images and i want to style my picture tag and images inside. I've tried to use .test1 and .test2 selectors but both of them didn't work. So is there any way to style it? Thanks.

UPD. For example, i want to make a red border aroung the image: https://jsfiddle.net/842L3f1x/

```
<picture class="test1">
  <source class="test2" srcset="img/photo-city@1x.jpg" media="(max-width: 700px)">
  <source srcset="img/photo-city@2x.jpg">
  <img src="img/photo-city@2x.jpg" alt="Photo city">
</picture>
```

Comment: I was able to apply styles just fine in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/undoingtech/d2r328un/).  Perhaps you should post some of your CSS.

Comment: @UndoingTech thanks for answer. Ok, i want red border for picture. Here is what i have.
https://jsfiddle.net/842L3f1x/

Comment: See my edits in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/undoingtech/842L3f1x/1/).  I took off the `.test2` styling completely and added `display: inline-block;` to `.test1`.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Also, be sure to test this rigorously.  It is "experimental" according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture).

Comment: @UndoingTech yes, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do this:

```
<picture >
  <source srcset="https://placehold.it/350x150" media="(max-width: 700px)">
  <source srcset="https://placehold.it/750x450">
  <img  class="test1" src="https://placehold.it/750x450" alt="Photo city">
</picture>
```

It does the exact output that you need; red border around an img, and you don't need the 2nd CSS class. As the comments say, be very careful about using 'experimental' features; you risk not supporting users of certain browsers, as well as the feature may change in the future and break functionality in your site.